# Can I try out AWS Lambda locally without a AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to deploy a fully localized AWS Lambda Serverless application on my home server (ironic I know), to evaluate AWS.
I saw that it was possible to deploy lambda with a docker container, although I found no Information on how to set that up.
So is it even possible to try out AWS lambda without creating a AWS account?

Comment: https://localstack.cloud/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS have a solution with [SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) (Serverless Application Model) which includes a feature to run your Lambda locally.

It will pull down an official Docker image created by the AWS team that will be able to run the Docker runtime. Whilst this will enable you test out some of the functionality of a simple Lambda function, you will not be able to use other Lambda functions that are reliant on configuration within AWS such as [Lambda Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html).

Once you have setup your AWS account its also worth knowing that AWS Free-Tier grants 1 million free Lambda invocations per month and this is a lifetime offer (does not expire).

Comment: I mostly just dont want my stuff online before it needs to be

Comment: Sure fair does, have a great day :)

Comment: yeah pretty sure i need an account though

Comment: You shouldn't need an account for the AWS SAM CLI, if it asks for a key you should be able to enter any string as this would only be used to deploy your Lambda (which SAM is also possible of).

Answer (score 2):

You may try using [Chalice Framework](https://aws.github.io/chalice/). It is a microservice framework and easier than other options available.

- You will not have to use docker.
- You can test Lambda Functions locally by setting a local API with simple command as `chalice local`.